# Why can't I repartition my SQL Server table because of a missing "next used filegroup?"

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I'm running certain application job that works with SQL Server database.
I'm getting this error:

> The partition scheme '`<partition_scheme_name>`' does not have any next used filegroup. Partition scheme has not been changed.

I've found a solution on the web and ran the following:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [dbo.partition_scheme_name]   
NEXT USED [PRIMARY];
```

But the same error is still shown. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure `ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [dbo.paretition_schame_name] NEXT USED [PRIMARY];` didn't throw some kind of an error due to the `dbo.` part of the name? Maybe try `ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [paretition_schame_name] NEXT USED [PRIMARY];` instead?

Comment: Both ALTER commands didn't show any error. Yet, the job is still failing with the same message ...

Answer (score 3):

Try altering scheme and then alter partition function:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [partition_scheme_name]   
NEXT USED [PRIMARY];

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [partition_function]
SPLIT RANGE ([new value])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in SMO, you have to do a ps.Alter() after you assign the NextUsedFileGroup...